# Can't Create an Event with ApplescriptObjC (but Code works in straight Applescript)

Tags: date, calendar, applescript, applescript-objc

I've been stuck on this for days.  I am trying to retrieve a date from user input and use it to create an event entry on the Calendar.  This works in Applescript:

```
tell application "Calendar"
  tell calendar "Home"
    set theDate to date loadInDate
    make new event at end with properties {description:job_name, summary:title_,   location:location_, start date:theDate}
 end tell
end tell
```

Where loadInDate is a text string formed as (userMonth & "/" & userDay & "/" & userYear & " " & userTime)

But when I paste this code into ApplescriptObjC and retrieve loadInDate from a user input string, it errors out "Can't get date from type string."  If I replace the variable "theDate" with a string "09/08/2014 15:00" it runs fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
J

```
script AppDelegate
property parent : class "NSObject"

-- IBOutlets
property window : missing value
property liString : ""



on buttonClicked_(sender)

   set loadInDate to liString as text
    tell application "Calendar"
        tell calendar "Bills"
            make event at end with properties {start date: date loadInDate, summary:loadInDate, location:"Here"}
        end tell
    end tell

end buttonClicked_

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_

end script
```

Answer (score 1):

If the class of the loadInDate variable is a `NSString`, convert it to an AppleScript string

```
set theDate to date (loadInDate as text)
```

--

**Updated:**

I tested, and i found a bug of the "**Calendar**" application when the date is a variable in the `tell calendar "x"` block.

In Xcode: **AppDelegate buttonClicked:]: Invalid date and time date 10/10/2014 of «class wres» Bills. (error -30720)**

In ApplesScript Editor: error "Invalid date and time date 10/10/2014 of calendar Bills." number -30720

This works (I tested with a "**10/10/2014**" in a `NSTextField`):

```
 on buttonClicked_(sender)
        set loadInDate to (tFld's stringValue()) as text
        tell application "Calendar"
            make new event at end of calendar "Bills" with properties {start date:date loadInDate ,summary:loadInDate, location:"Here"}
        end tell
 end buttonClicked_
```

Replace **(tFld's stringValue())** by **liString** in the script.

Comment: Thanks, but it leads to 2014-09-12 14:44:00.904 Trifecta[4634:303] *** -[AppDelegate buttonClicked:]: Invalid date and time date 10/10/2014 of «class wres» Bills. (error -30720), full code relisted in main post.

Comment: You're a life safer!  Thank you so much!